# C++ - struct constructor, redefinition error when trying to derefence a pointer to the struct

Tags: c++, constructor

When defining a constructor overload whose only purpose is to dereference a value I get an error that I'd like to understand.

Here's the code:

```
struct _tv {
    string t;
    void* v;
    _tv(string _t, void* _v) {
        t = _t;
        v = _v;
    };
    _tv(_tv* v) { _tv(*v); }; // A
};
```

And it fails to compile because of:

```
error: redefinition of 'v'
  _tv(_tv* v) { _tv(*v); };
```

What I want to do is to be able to construct _tv's like this:

```
// Suppose 'a' is a valid _tv*
_tv* b = new _tv(a); // B
```

If I drop that line (A) from my code, it compiles and I could achieve the same result with:

```
_tv* b = new _tv(*a);
```

But I don't want that, I want to understand why it doesn't work and why the error states that I'm trying to redefine the argument 'v'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_tv(*v);
```

Declares a variable of type "pointer to `_tv`". The name of that variable is `v`.

Consider [dcl.meaning]/6:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> *( D1 )*
>
> the type of the contained *declarator-id* is the same as that of the
>   contained *declarator-id* in the declaration
>
> ```
>   T D1
> ```
>
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but
>   they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

It seems you want to use delegating constructors:

```
_tv(_tv* v) : _tv(*v) {}
```

And define an appropriate copy constructor (if necessary).

Comment: Mmm, ok, so how should I declare the constructor in order to achieve the desired behavior? (Line marked w/ B)

Comment: You can use a copy constructor `_tv(_tv const& v)` and not use the constructor you have.

Comment: @almosnow You mean define? But what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: The delegated constructor solved it. I wanted to create copies of a _tv* directly without derefencing on the new() call. Apparently it works now, thanks a lot!. And now I'll dive into how delegate contructors work...

Answer (score 1):

```
struct _tv {
    string t;
    void* v;
    _tv(string _t, void* _v) {
        t = _t;
        v = _v;
    }
    _tv(_tv* ptr) {
        t = ptr->t;
        v = ptr->v;
    } // A
};
```

What you'r trying to do is constructor delegration, algo need the pointer called ptr to not shadow v
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement

also leading underscore names are reserved
[What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)